# Muramasa Blade's effect on The Hulk

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

Could the **Muramasa Blade** block **Hulk's** regeneration capability?

Comment: Possibly, but not in a way that would matter. The Hulk's powers appears to be challenge-oriented. The more something works to suppress his powers, the more likely his powers will slowly adapt to overcome it. The Muramasa Blade may work for a time early in any fight with the Hulk, but as soon as he doesn't regenerate, his body will start changing  to compensate. He may grow stronger, or faster or both as his rage levels increase due to damage. Either he will adapt to start healing again, or the enemy had better be able to kill him quickly. Otherwise, he will devastate them.

Answer (score 12):

If the Hulk was a mutant, I'd expect his healing powers to be inhibited by the Murumasa Blade in the same way as Wolverine, Sabertooth and Daken's all were. What these three all have in common is their healing powers all come from their mutant gene.

But the Hulk doesn't have the mutant gene, his powers came from a super dose of gamma radiation, so until someone cuts him or some other gamma powered character, we can't really know for sure how their healing powers would react.

Comment: I was under the impression that he essentially did have a mutant gene. When he got his gamma dose he was changed (presumably at a generic level) and that is why he continues to have his abilities. It's not like he is continously getting a super dose of gamma radiation.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg He is a mutate not a mutant.  Mutates have several differences including not having the X gene show up on scanners.  While there may be some wierd genetics, he is not a mutant.

Comment: @kaine To be mutated makes you a [mutant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mutant).  He might not be the same as the X-Men mutants (X gene), but he has mutated from  the norm.

Comment: @Trisped but he's doesn't have the mutant-gene so he wouldn't be a mutant in the same way as Wolverine would. Which I think was Kaine's point.

Comment: @Trisped but I guess you're correct as well.

Comment: @Trisped Mutate and mutant are words defined in the Marvel universe to mean different things.  While you are correct if you are using the words as they are used on this earth, on Earth 616 there is an important distinction.  Google "mutate marvel".

Comment: @Trisped Also note that "Mutate" as I am using it is a noun.  It means "one who was mutated" not "one who mutated".  Subtle but important distinction.